# How do I get Code Folding in Vim for shell scripts working

Tags: bash, shell, vim, folding

Whatever I do, I don't seem to get syntax folding running for shell scripts.

So I have a file called `abc.sh` call

```
:let g:sh_fold_enabled=7
:let g:is_bash=1
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

But it still can't find any folds. Why is that?

Comment: With `foldmethod=syntax`, the folds are defined by syntax items with the "fold" argument. If your syntax file doesn't define them as such, you'll get no folds.

Comment: What version of vim? What does `:set ft?|filetype` output in vim with that file loaded?

Comment: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 23 2016 14:27:29)`, `set ft` results in `sh`. I can't believe there is no builtin support for shell scripts, I mean there is even support for python or ruby, but not for shell scripts?

Answer (score 10):

This problem is solved in a discussion on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1rvcqe/bash_folding_not_working/).

The trick is to put those commands into your **vimrc** at the **top**.

```
set nocompatible

filetype plugin indent on

set foldenable

set foldmethod=marker

au FileType sh let g:sh_fold_enabled=5

au FileType sh let g:is_bash=1

au FileType sh set foldmethod=syntax

syntax enable
```

IMO fold-level 5 works better than 7, so that's what I put into the code above.

I put the above just after my plugins section.

This question is also discussed, with a slightly different solution, in the following post: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413015/a-problem-with-folding-bash-functions-in-vim).

Comment: It seems a key detail of the above is to make sure `filetype plugin indent on` runs before `syntax enable`. Folding silently fails if reversing their order. A possible way to enforce that in more complex configurations might be to use something like `au FileType sh syntax enable` for every applicable filetype, rather than enabling syntax highlighing globally.